# Oracle Query on 3 tables with 2 outer joins

Tags: oracle11g, outer-join, ansi-sql

persons - a table of user names:

```
per_id      number(10) - primary key, populated by a sequence
user_name   varchar2(50)
user_id     varchar2(15) - unique, basically the employee ID
```

work_assignments - like crew assignments, but more general:

```
wa_id     number(10) - primary key, populated by a sequence
wa_name   varchar2(25)
```

current_assignments - which users have which work_assignments; the average per user is about 25 work assignments, but some individuals have upwards of 150:

```
wa_id   number(10)
per_id  number(10)
```

I'm trying to write a query that will compare the work_assignments for two users, in a total of three columns.  The results should look like this:

```
WA_Name   User_Name1    User_Name2
Crew A    Bob           Joe
Crew B                  Joe
Crew C    Bob
```

That is, every work_assignment that either of the two user has, with the name(s) of the user(s) who has it.

```
select distinct * from (
  select wa.name      work_assignment,
         per.name     user_name1,
         per2.name    user_name2
    from work_assignments  wa join current_assignments ca  on wa.wa_id = ca.wa_id
                              join current_assignments ca2 on wa.wa_id = ca2.wa_id
                   left outer join persons per  on per.per_id  = ca.per_id  and per.user_id  = 'X12345'
                   left outer join persons per2 on per2.per_id = ca2.per_id and per2.user_id = 'Y67890'
                   )
   where user_name1 is not null or user_name2 is not null
   order by 1;
```

The problem is that if both users have a work assignment, it shows 3 records: one for Bob, one for Joe, and one for both:

```
WA_Name   User_Name1    User_Name2
Crew A    Bob           Joe
Crew A                  Joe
Crew A    Bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a set of sample data/tables

```
drop table persons;
drop table work_assgn;
drop table curr_assgn;


create table persons(
  per_id number(10) not null
, user_name varchar2(10) not null
, user_id varchar2(10) not null
)
;

insert into persons values( 1, 'Bob', 'X123' );
insert into persons values( 2, 'Joe', 'Y456' );
insert into persons values( 3, 'Mike', 'Z789' );
insert into persons values( 4, 'Jeff', 'J987' );

commit;

create table work_assgn(
  wa_id number(10) not null
, wa_name varchar2(25)
)
;

insert into work_assgn values( 10, 'Crew A' );
insert into work_assgn values( 20, 'Crew B' );
insert into work_assgn values( 30, 'Crew C' );
insert into work_assgn values( 40, 'Crew D' );

commit;

create table curr_assgn(
  wa_id number(10) not null
, per_id number(10) not null
)
;

insert into curr_assgn values( 10, 1 );
insert into curr_assgn values( 10, 2 );
insert into curr_assgn values( 20, 2 );
insert into curr_assgn values( 30, 1 );
insert into curr_assgn values( 40, 4 );

commit;


select * from persons;
select * from work_assgn;
select * from curr_assgn;
```

So the data looks like

```
PERSONS
    PER_ID USER_NAME  USER_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Bob        X123
         2 Joe        Y456
         3 Mike       Z789
         4 Jeff       J987


WORK_ASSGN
     WA_ID WA_NAME
---------- -------------------------
        10 Crew A
        20 Crew B
        30 Crew C
        40 Crew D

CURRASSGN
     WA_ID     PER_ID
---------- ----------
        10          1
        10          2
        20          2
        30          1
        40          4
```

One approach may be to use a PIVOT

```
with assignment as
(
select  p.user_id, p.user_name, a.wa_name
from persons p
join curr_assgn c
  on p.per_id =c.per_id
join work_assgn a
  on a.wa_id = c.wa_id
where p.user_id in ( 'X123', 'Y456' )
)
select * from assignment
pivot
( max(user_name) for user_id in ( 'X123', 'Y456' )
)
;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in an organization as large as ours, user_name is not unique.  I can identify over 1400 names that have more than one entry in the persons table.  That's why I have to join on user_id.  I tried this using user_id rather than user_name, but it gave me all the work_assignments even if neither Joe nor Bob was assigned to it.  Is there a way to filter out those records that have neither user?  I'm not familiar with PIVOT.

Comment: @AndyDan so that means you could have a 1400 column wide report ?

Comment: No, I would never be comparing the work assignments for more than 2 people at a time.  The report should be only 3 columns: work assignment name, user name 1, user name 2.  It's just that we might have 3 or 4 "Joe"s, so I can't filter just on user name.  But I would rather have the user name in the report than the user id.

Comment: @AndyDan Ah, so you would be filtering by per_id. I see that now in your original question, but I did not make the connection. In your outer join solution, you are JOINing on the per_id; often this I not semantically what is required. The PIVOT was introduced in 11g, and is a way to turn rows into columns to create a cross-tab style report. Let me rework my answer...

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out after I found some PIVOT examples in the Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference manual.  Let me post my query here in a minute, and see what you think.  It does seem to be returning the same results as my "ugly" query mentioned in the original post.

Comment: OK, I updated my example, let me know if that works for you

Comment: In order to limit the result to only the work assignments that these two people have, the ASSIGNMENT query needs to include "where p.user_id in ('X123', 'Y456')".  Otherwise, it displays all work assignments, but most have no names by them.

Comment: @AndyDan. Let me update my answer, with the sample data I am using, because I do not get the assignments with no names issue. So it might just be the way I am constructing the data

Comment: Just remember that there will be data in all 3 tables that have nothing to do with the 2 users being compared.  Looks like your curr_assgns table only has data for user_ids 1 and 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136263/discussion-between-bobc-and-andydan).